# $g^{(n)}(1)=\frac{(f^{(n)}(1))^{a}}{(n!)^{a-1}}, a>0$; Prove that g can be extended to an entire function.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be entire and $g(z)$ be an analytic function in a neighborhood of $z=1$ which satisfies$$g^{(n)}(1)=\frac{(f^{(n)}(1))^{a}}{(n!)^{a-1}}, a>0$$ Prove that g can be extended to an entire function.

My thought:

Since $f$ is entire, $f$ has a Taylor series expansion at $z=1$ as $$f(z)=f(1)+f'(1)z+\frac{f''(1)}{2!}z^2+...$$
Where the coefficients are somehow related to $g$. But how can I possibly show that $g$ can be extended to an entire function? My guess is using Cauchy estimates, but since $f$ is entire, I'm not sure how I can bound the function itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that by the assumption that $f$ is entire, we have
$$
\limsup_{n\to \infty}\Big|\frac{f^{(n)}(1)}{n!}\Big|^{\frac{1}{n}}=0.
$$ This is because $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(1)}{n!}(z-1)^n$ has a radius of convergence equal to $$R=\left(\limsup_{n\to \infty}\Big|\frac{f^{(n)}(1)}{n!}\Big|^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)^{-1}=\infty.$$ Now, note that the power series
$$
G(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{g^{(n)}(1)}{n!}(z-1)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left[\frac{f^{(n)}(1)}{n!}\right]^a(z-1)^n
$$ has a radius of convergence equal to
$$
\left(\limsup_{n\to \infty}\Big|\frac{f^{(n)}(1)}{n!}\Big|^{\frac{a}{n}}\right)^{-1}=0^{-1}=\infty.
$$ Thus $G$ defines an entire function. Suppose $g$ was initially defined on a connected open set $\Omega \supset \{|z-1|<\alpha\}$. Since $G^{(n)}(1)=g^{(n)}(1)$ for all $n\ge 0$, it follows that $G$ and $g$ coincide on $|z-1|<\alpha$. By the identity theorem, it follows that $g=G$ on $\Omega$. This proves $G$ is an entire extension of $g$.

Comment: Where did the power of $\frac{1}{n}$ come from?

Comment: @YaG It comes from the root test of convergence. The root test: A series of complex numbers $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j$ converges if $\limsup_j |a_j|^{1/j}<1$ and diverges if $\limsup_j |a_j|^{1/j}>1$. You may be able to find it in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence and related post about the root test.